# How to set a default Postfix for PhraseExpress?

Tags: autocomplete, phraseexpress

I'm using PhraseExpress v.11 on Windows 8.1 mainly for the auto-complete feature. Is it possible to set the default **Postfix** for a *new phrase* to `SmartComplete`? Currently I need to select *SmartComplete* from the dropdown menu for every new phrase - really annoying if you do this 100+ times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you haven't done it, create a folder for your SmartComplete
   phrases.
2. Then switch to Expert Mode and apply the postfix
   SmartComplete to the folder.
3. Then move all phrases for which you
   want SmartComplete to that new folder. Any new phrase created in
   that folder will get the SmartComplete postfix.