# PhraseExpress AutoSuggest doesn't pick up repeatedly typed words

Tags: autocomplete, phraseexpress

I'm using PhraseExpress v11 and the AutoSuggest feature doesn't pick up repeatedly typed words automatically. 
I'm using it for more than 2 weeks and the AutoSuggest list picked up 10 words only. (an example: I typed the word *PhraseExpress* more than 10 times and it's still missing in the AutoSuggest list)
Is there something I can do about or do I need to add each word manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really force it. In my experience PhraseExpress learns better when you type words in context. Typing a single word like "PhraseExpress" repeatedly rarely works, and users do not like too many suggetions. To boot, the word has a capital letter in the middle, so this may srew with AutoSuggest. Sometimes it does seam arbitrary which words get learnt and which ones do not.

If PhraseExpress is too picky when it comes to AutoSuggest, you can turn on a few more options in the settings:

[image: PhraseExpress AutoSuggest settings]

If it still does not help, you may want to suggest improvements in the PhraseExpress forum (http://www.bartelsmedia.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=146) or contact the manufacturer (http://www.phraseexpress.com/contact.php).

Last, but not least, you can add the word as a phrase with the SmartComplete or "Incremental" settings, the way it was already answered here: [How to set a default Postfix for PhraseExpress?](https://superuser.com/questions/969553/how-to-set-a-default-postfix-for-phraseexpress).

Creating automatic learning functions is extremely hard and you may expect too much. Sometimes it is just easier to create an entry by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Hi from the PhraseExpress makers!

PhraseExpress learns and adds new words to the AutoComplete library from repetitively entered *whole **sentences*** only.

Programs cannot distinguish entering "words" from any random keyboard input so PhraseExpress needs a certain context of your input.